# codeception Example to Array

Tags: php, testing, codeception

Is there an implemented method to convert an Example to an Array so I can pass it right to a post request as parameters. Right now I have to do:

```
/**
     * @dataprovider invalidUserActivityRequestProvider
     */
    public function it_does_not_get_tracked_for_an_invalid_request(ApiTester $I, Example $example)
    {
        $userActivity = [
            'timestamp' => isset($example['timestamp']) ? $example['timestamp'] : null ,
            'email' => isset($example['email']) ? $example['email'] : null ,
            'type' => isset($example['type']) ? $example['type'] : null ,
            'duration' => isset($example['duration']) ? $example['duration'] : null ,
            'distance' => isset($example['distance']) ? $example['distance'] : null ,
            'repetitions' => isset($example['repetitions']) ? $example['repetitions'] : null ,
        ];

        $I->sendPOST('/useractivity', $userActivity);
        $I->seeResponseCodeIs(422);
    }

    protected function invalidUserActivityRequestProvider () : array {
        return [
            [
                'timestamp' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
                'email' => 'invalidUser@example.com',
                'type' => 'run',
                'duration' => 300,
                'distance' => 1000,
                'repetitions' => 1
            ],

            [
                'timestamp' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
                'email' => 'user@example.com',
                'type' => 'invalidType',
                'duration' => 300,
                'distance' => 1000,
                'repetitions' => 1
            ],

            [
                'timestamp' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
                'email' => 'user@example.com',
                'type' => 'run'
            ],
        ];
    }
```

but I would like something like:

```
public function it_does_not_get_tracked_for_an_invalid_request(ApiTester $I, Example $example)
    {
        $I->sendPOST('/useractivity', $example->toArray());
        $I->seeResponseCodeIs(422);
    }
```

Comment: `Example $example` means `$example` is an object of class `Example` but you are using it as an array `$example['timestamp']` so I have no idea what you're doing here.

Comment: However, `$I->sendPOST('/useractivity', (array)$example);`

Comment: @AbraCadaver Example allows to access properties this way. Please have a look at:
http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage

Comment: @AbraCadaver :) nonetheless casting it actually works

Comment: Yes, I don't know _codeception_ so maybe someone else will have a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Codeception, but casting is an option:

```
$I->sendPOST('/useractivity', (array)$example);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it works not really!...

Trying to assertEqual an `(array) $example` and an array results in:

```
- Expected | + Actual
@@ @@
Array (
-    Binary String: 0x002a0064617461 => Array (...)
+    'id' => 6
+    'unique_id' => '2199033651380'
+    'data' => Array (...)
+    'user_id' => 1
+    'brand_id' => 1
+    'infrastructure' => 'AT'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

From **PHP 7.4** you can use array spread operator. Since Codeception example object class (`Codeception\Example`) implements `ArrayAccess` interface you can use something like:

```
$I->sendPOST('/useractivity', [...$example]);
```